# Wordnik API Pointers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sdk, wordnik

I would like to use the [Wordnik API](http://developer.wordnik.com/) for my site but I am a bit confused as I am new to the world of API's and implementing them.

I do not have server side access and from what I can tell to use Wordnik you must use a server side script but I see they have Actionscript. I know that is Flash but have no experience with it.

Can I use [AS3 SDK](http://developer.wordnik.com/libraries/as3-sdk) to implement the Wordnik API without having server side access?

If that is possible can someone point me in the right direction for learning how Actionscript works so that I may be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use AS3 SDK to implement the Wordnik API without having server side access?

Yes it is possible with ActionScript without using server side scripting.

> can someone point me in the right direction for learning how Actionscript works so that I may be able to do this.

[Searching Google for ActionScript tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?cx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=actionscript%20tutorials) is one thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Great, thank you for the information, I will start researching now =>